# Class variables as Message placeholder which dynamically identify the name and replaces its value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and just a curious what might be the best way to replace the message placeholders dynamically in runtime with the DTO variables (this can be done using multiple ways like MessageFormat) but my requirement is that if i can refer to the variable name in message placeholder, then it should match the dto variable name in runtime and replaces its value. For example;

```
Class Message{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String message;
...
}


messages.properties
email.message=Hello {firstName}, how are you doing? This is to inform you that {message}.
```

**Requirement:**

```
email.message=Hello {lastName}, how are you doing? This is to inform you that {message}.
```

Can i change the placeholder as lastName instead of firstName without changing any code base and now it must take the value of lastName at runtime.